# add javascript datetime inside a html url

Tags: javascript, html

For a cache issue, I want to send the current datetime with a url, but with the following code, the current timestamp isn't shown in the url..

```
<script>var d=new Date();</script>
<li><a href="/controllername?t="+d.getTime()+"&name=.... // etc
```

How to add javascript datatime properly in the url?

Comment: can't you use php date() function..... date('Y-m-d H:i:s')..??

Comment: I develop in Classic ASP, but it is necessary for cache to post the datetime with javascript

Comment: you are trying to use javascript outside the <script></script> tags

Comment: I know, but how to put the d.GetTime() value inside the html

Comment: You need to send most recent time value with url as shown in my example, problem with Bruno's code is that time gets appended to _href_ value at page load that represents time when you loaded the page which can be different from the time you clicked the link.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using inline javascript a better approach would be to identify your element in the DOM and then simply set it's `href` attribute like the following:

*html*

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="timeLink" href="#">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Time Link</a></li>
</ul>​​​​​​
```

*javascript*

```
var d=new Date();
var timeLink = document.getElementById("timeLink");

timeLink.setAttribute("href","/controllername?t="+d.getTime());
```

As usual, using `jQuery` can simplify a lot:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    $("#timeLink").attr("href","/controllername?t="+d.getTime());
});​
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dU6xH/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `new Date().getTime();` and attach it to the link

```
<a id="link" href="/controllername?t="+d.getTime()+"&name=.... // etc
```

by grabbing the `link` element and appending the timestamp:

```
var link = ​document.getElementById('link');​​
var now = new Date().getTime();
link.setAttribute("href", "/controllername?t=" + now);
```

Since you want to add the **current** timestamp when you click on a link, I would attach the above code to the `onclick` function of the `href`, so when you click on the link the actual timestamp will be appended to the url. See the example http://jsfiddle.net/GBBdc/.

Comment: this solution should be preferred, as it will attach the current datetime to the link at the moment of clicking, not the datetime of the event when the dom loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="this.href='/controllername?t=' + (new Date().getTime());">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using ASP You can define your script as this. You can do any format you like (.ToString("hh:mm:ss") ) for example

```
<script>        var d = '<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>';</script>
```

This way you can have any format and use it backend any way you like, always ensuring you have the correct format, as apposed to client side strings which may be in a localized format

Comment: But how to pass that value to my url?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the d object if you are not inside `<Script>`

do something like:

```
<script>
var d=new Date();
$("#mylink").attr("href","...." + d.getTime() + "..");

</script>

<a id="mylink">
```

Answer (score 0):

Time gets changed with every second, millisecond etc. so you need to send most recent time value with url:

```
<a href="javascript:sendRequest('/controllername?t=');">Send Request</a>
```

*Javascript:*

```
function sendRequest(oldUrl){
    var d = new Date();
    var newUrl = oldUrl + d.getTime();
    window.location = newUrl;
}
```

Here's is its **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JMhWJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Very easy just write this in your script

var d = '';